# I changed gravity but button position is same

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]

Can you explain please why it isn't changing when I change gravity. First when I changed it position of button was changed but now I can't change position.

main.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="92dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/button1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: poste some code it is help for repley ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set this property for related layout **android:layout_width="match_parent"** for LinearLayout
(parent Layout)

Comment: Why didn't this automatically changed when I changed this from Graphical Layout?

Answer (score 1):

You are setting gravity of button which will result in set your view's layout. for example if you have text on button, and you set gravity center, then it will center align the text into button, to set gravity of component into its parent, you need to set parent's gravity.

So Change your code to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="92dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/button1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you need to set the property "layout_width" of the parent layout (i.e. the LinearLayout that contains the button) to fill_parent.